# Should I commit cosmetic changes?

Tags: coding-style, version-control, commit

There are minor coding style changes that I often want to commit to the source control, but now the change log is full of those changes that do not affect code functionality.

What should I do next time I have to fix minor things like:

- Remove and sort usings (in .NET, imports in python, includes in c++)
- Correct indentation, spacing and line breaks

Comment: maybe this should get the "subjective" tag?

Comment: Commit often, that's what scm tools are for. In my opinion, by no means the scm log has to be viewed as a proper ChangeLog

Comment: @Gregory where do you put the changelog then?

Comment: I maintain a change log separately for each releasable item (i.e. library, etc) that I release. I build the changelog when I prepare the release. Yes, this means I need to manually look over the code and work out what's new and why but that (IMHO) is a GOOD thing. This approach means that the change log can be in more appropriate language than the commit comments.

Comment: It would seem useful at this point to specify the type of source control you're using since the answers/discussion are getting rather fine-grained. For example, i mostly use SVN where every commit can be documented, the log is easily accessible and branching/tagging can be easily used to separate and mark your BIG releases.

Comment: besides, from one version to the next, there might be hundreds of revisions. Interpreting each of them as a line in a change log is way too low-level for most people. Imho a change log should contain high-level descriptions of changes, while the commit messages only serve as a low-level description of what changed in the source.

Comment: And maybe _adding comments_ is one of those cosmetic changes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are changing the code file, I don't really see why you wouldn't want to commit and share those changes.  If you don't you run the risk that someone else will fix them and then collide with yours.

If they aren't changes that other users want in the codebase, perhaps you should ask yourself why you are spending time writing them.

Comment: And if you're not just going to annoy everyone with endless whitespace/cosmetic diffs.

Comment: No - I frequently submit whitespace/cosmetic changes, and tend to hope I'm not annoying people.

Comment: Since you've got version control, if someone doesn't like your cosmetic changes, they can revert them out.  No big deal.

Comment: @Mike - yes, but since a lot of people get notified every time I submit changes, these changes can end up creating a lot of noise.

Answer (score 27):

Do commit them, with the commit comment flagged appropriately to make it easier to ignore when skimming through a list of changes.

Don't commit them in the same operation as a change to functionality. That way, if you do break something, it is easier to narrow down what broke it and is easy to revert just the refactoring if necessary.

Comment: This is really important. Commiting whitespace changes together with functional changes is dangerous. It makes it hard for people to figure out what really changed.

And, like everybody else said, make sure the cosmetic changes are easily recognisable from their commit messages. (You do use commit messages on every commit, right?)

Answer (score 25):

Don't commit them together with unrelated fixes.

I would commit them, but add some predefined keyword to the commit message. Messages with this keyword could then be ignored when generating change logs.

You could use a prefix like `[cleanup]` for instance.

```
[cleanup] Removed some whitespace
[cleanup] Changed format
Fixed some major bug.
[cleanup] Corrected indentation
```

Comment: [cosmetic] is also suitable as keyword, it indicates it's a cleanup that does not do any functional change.

Answer (score 6):

On projects where I'm the only developer I tend to do these kind of fix ups along with other code changes.

On projects where there's a team of us I tend to try and commit these kind of changes on their own so that they don't obscure the 'real work'.

I feel that it's important to fix everything that's 'wrong' with a codebase even if it's purely minor things like indentation.

Answer (score 5):

There's a couple of issues.

First, don't do changes to the code because you're bored and doesn't have enough real tasks. If this is the case, go talk to your project manager and get some real tasks assigned to you, something with value.

In other words, don't go changing the code for the sake of the change. Always add some value to the code in the process.

Now, if those changes are contributing to making the code easier to handle, by you, and others, then do them. Things like ensuring naming standards are followed, refactor crufty code, etc. But get a task for it, so that your project manager can say "Yes, this is good, spend 2 hours on this and get back to me."

Commit the changes when you're done with them. Don't lop them together with whatever real task you finished just before them, or the next one, it will make merging bugfixes between branches, code reviews, and just general code browsing, hard to follow.

> "Ok, so you fixed bug 7711, and also changed about 100 other files. Nice, so what is actually the bugfix here?"

Answer (score 4):

I think this depends on your work environment and how others working on the same project want to deal with that which is likely to differ.

So, my general suggestion would be to ask the people working with the same code and coming up with a guideline for cases like that. You might find that people don't mind check-ins due to cosmetic changes or that they would rather live with a bit of "unprettiness" rather than dealing with cluttered change logs.

A definitive guideline that is transparent to everyone is the best way to deal with these questions and avoid confusion in the future.

Personally, I like tidied up code and wouldn't mind check-ins due to purely cosmetic changes. However, if it is just a bit of spacing and line breaks, I would probably just let it be and only change it if I was working on the same code file anyway. I often remove and sort usings because I find it confusing if there are a whole bunch of usings that don't make sense, but that's just me.

Answer (score 4):

I think when you’ve got a team of developers working on the same code, the most important thing is to agree a cosmetic style for code. So, your first task is to try to get your entire team to agree on a coding style.

Good luck.

Once you’ve done that, commit cosmetic changes as often as you want, to remind people to stick to the style.

There’s a great section in Code Complete about the merits of different coding styles. If you can get your team to read the section before your coding style meeting, it might help to <del>get you all out of the meeting alive</del> focus the discussion.

Comment: I almost completely agree. First, have a coding style written down that everyone agrees to.

However, frequently committing cosmetic changes will not make you popular with other developers in your team. Instead, I'd rather do a complete coding style cleanup and commit it in one go. There may be specific points of time in the production cycle where such a cleanup can preferably get done.

Comment: @nikai: good point. I reckon some repeated commits early on can save repeated code clean-up work later on (people do have to learn somehow), but there are of course loads of times within the production cycle when the coding style isn’t the priority.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely commit them. If you commit them along with real code changes and you have to roll back those changes, then you lose your cosmetic fixes.

Ideally, commits should be like database transactions: a chunk of related working code that can be rolled back without affecting the rest of the system.

Answer (score 1):

If the changes are to things which might be in any way controversial (position of brackets for example) then make sure you've agreed a code style with the rest of your team.  Don't just change it to your own preferred style then check it in.  Otherwise someone else might then change it back and check their changes in, then you change it back to your way...

Answer (score 0):

Are these "minor" things fixes? If yes, commit them. If no, don't.

Really, it depends on what you and your team consider important.

Answer (score 0):

i like to commit often. Certainly any time there's an appreciable change. It's easy that way. If you start to compartmentalize code snippets and try and commit some sooner rather than later you will eventually forget to commit something very important.

In short: Commit often and ALWAYS document the change. When there's a HUGE change, tag it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't commit just for the sake of commiting. I usually add those for the code I'm working on. For example if I'm fixing a bug in method A I make sure to also make all cosmetic changes as well.

IMO you guys are missing coding tools like PMD, JIndent, etc that take care of this issues as you code. Some IDE's like Netebeans show this "issues" as warnings. So its not a random/personal change is following standards.

Answer (score -5):

Commit them with the next big change as sidenote. At least that's what I'd do.

Comment: -1 - that'll make working out what's actually changed in your big change impossible. Whitespace/cosmetic changes should always be separate, so actual changes are easier to see.

Comment: But then perhaps merging a simple bugfix to another branch, a released version, might gets noisy because the changeset contains lots of unrelated changes.

Comment: @Dominic, Lasse: You guys are right...I totally missed that there's also the changeset for each commit, which would be crowded with the whitespace changes...sorry.